# instantiating a page object in Ruby with Selenium and Cucumber

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I'm trying to automatize a browser to navigate a website and click on different pages. To do this I have two classes AllPages and SearchPage which inherits from AllPages.

The first thing I do is instantiate AllPages, go to the website and click a link which leads me to a Searchpage, at which point I try to instantiate SearchPage using these lines of code

AllPages:

```
def return_search_page browser
    @browser = browser
end
```

Steps:

```
  @newpage = AllPages.new @browser
  @searchpage = @newpage.return_search_page @newpage
  @searchpage.find_searchbox
```

the error i get trying to run this is: 
"undefined method `find_searchbox' for #< AllPages:0x00000002632cf0> (NoMethodError)"

My method find_searchbox which is located in SearchPage is this

```
def find_searchbox
    @browser.find_element(:class, "searchbox")
end
```

I'm guessing i'm freaking up the instantiation of the object @searchpage, since that's in a scenario that comes after opening the browser and navigating to the website.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def return_search_page browser
  SearchPage.new browser
end

@newpage = AllPages.new @browser
@searchpage = @newpage.return_search_page @browser
@searchpage.find_searchbox
```

And if you are setting @browser in your initialize, you wouldn't need to pass it in as a parameter to #return_seearch_page

Comment: Thanks! it helped but now i'm getting a different message
"undefined method `find_element' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)"

Comment: You typically create a browser instance in a test, pass it into the Page object when you initialize it, then set an instance variable inside the def initialize (@browser = browser).

Comment: So if I instantiated the browser in a different scenario, how can I set that instance in another scenario. Like, it'd be easy if i had a global page variable or if i only had one scenario, but i'm lost with multiple pages and scenarios

Comment: If this answer helped you, please accept it as the answer. If you have another question, please post it in a new question.

Comment: Take a look at Cucumber hooks file, you can define your browser there to run before your tests. Lots of documentation out there on this.